# Macros, Variables and Includes

Tags: templating, plugin-craftcommerce, variable, macro

Trying to get my head around this and make my code a little DRYer.

I have a `_helpers` macro file. Like so:

```
{% macro date_formatted(givenDate) %}
    {{ givenDate|date("l, jS F Y") }}
{% endmacro %}

{% macro product_title(product) %}
    {{ product|replace(' HA', '<sup>HA</sup>')|raw }}
{% endmacro %}
```

This file is used in various places throughout the website and is included in various base templates using `{% import '_macros/_helpers' as helpers %}`

I then have another macro for creating products (teasers and various code that would be repeated). This contains:

```
  {% macro teaser(product, imgSize, className) %}
    {% set cart = craft.commerce.getCart() %}
    {% set category = product.category.first() %}
    {% import '_macros/_helpers' as helpers %}

    <div class="product-teaser{% if className %} // {{ className }}{% endif %}">
        {% set thumbAsset = product.productImage.first() %}
        {% if thumbAsset %}
        <a href="{{ product.url }}">
            <img
                src="{{ craft.imager.transformImage(thumbAsset, { width:imgSize, height:imgSize })}}"
                srcset="{{ craft.imager.transformImage(thumbAsset, { width:imgSize, height:imgSize })}} 1x, {{ craft.imager.transformImage(thumbAsset, { width:imgSize * 2, height:imgSize * 2 }) }} 2x"
                alt="{{ product.title }}"
                class="product-teaser__img"
            />
        </a>
        {% endif %}
        <h3 class="product-teaser__title{% if className %} // {{ className }}__title{% endif %}">{{ helpers.product_title(product.title) }}</h3>
        <p class="product-teaser__price{% if className %} // {{ className }}__price{% endif %}">{{ product.defaultPrice|currency(cart.currency) }}</p>

        <p>
            <a href="{{ product.url }}" class="btn // btn--sub">View Product</a>

            {% if className == "product-teaser--featured" %}
                <a href="{{ category.url }}" class="btn // btn--base">{{ category.title }} Range</a>
            {% endif %}
        </p>
    </div>
{% endmacro %}


{% macro alsoPurchased(product, imgSize) %}
    {% set cart = craft.commerce.getCart() %}
    {% import '_macros/_helpers' as helpers %}

    <li class="productAlsoPurchased__item">
        {% set thumbAsset = product.productImage.first() %}
        {% if thumbAsset %}
        <a href="{{ product.url }}">
            <img
                src="{{ craft.imager.transformImage(thumbAsset, { width:imgSize, height:imgSize })}}"
                srcset="{{ craft.imager.transformImage(thumbAsset, { width:imgSize, height:imgSize })}} 1x, {{ craft.imager.transformImage(thumbAsset, { width:imgSize * 2, height:imgSize * 2 }) }} 2x"
                alt="{{ product.title }}"
                class="productAlsoPurchased__img"
            />
        </a>
        {% endif %}
        <p class="productAlsoPurchased__content">
            <strong>{{ helpers.product_title(product.title) }}</strong><br />
            <span class="product-teaser__price">{{ product.defaultPrice|currency(cart.currency) }}</span>
        </p>
    </li>
{% endmacro %}
```

The problem/question I have come up against is that it seems I have to include `{% import '_macros/_helpers' as helpers %}` in each Macro and also the same goes for setting the variable for cart. `{% set cart = craft.commerce.getCart() %}`

Is there a better way of doing this? Or a DRYer way of doing this? So I don't have to repeat my includes and setting of variables for each Macro block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't able to pass an import into a macro. So `helpers` needs to be imported into each macro file that uses it.

You can however pass the `cart` to your macros. As a side note, it's definitely best to set the `cart` variable in a global template - this means you're only ever setting it once. All templates that extend this global template then inherit `cart`. The way macro's work though means they need to have these variables *explicitly passed to them*. They don't inherit variables in the same way includes do or when you extend templates.

You can then pass `cart` to your macro like so:

```
{# Variable set in an extended template or current template #}
{% set cart = craft.commerce.cart %}

{# Variable is passed to the macro #}
{{ teaser(product, imgSize, className, cart) }}
```

Macro file then edited to take variables:

```
{% macro teaser(product, imgSize, className, cart) %}
    {# We still need to import our helpers into this macro file #}
    {% import '_macros/_helpers' as helpers %}

    {% set category = product.category.first() %}

    <div class="product-teaser{% if className %} // {{ className }}{% endif %}">
        {% set thumbAsset = product.productImage.first() %}
        {% if thumbAsset %}
        <a href="{{ product.url }}">
            <img
                src="{{ craft.imager.transformImage(thumbAsset, { width:imgSize, height:imgSize })}}"
                srcset="{{ craft.imager.transformImage(thumbAsset, { width:imgSize, height:imgSize })}} 1x, {{ craft.imager.transformImage(thumbAsset, { width:imgSize * 2, height:imgSize * 2 }) }} 2x"
                alt="{{ product.title }}"
                class="product-teaser__img"
            />
        </a>
        {% endif %}
        <h3 class="product-teaser__title{% if className %} // {{ className }}__title{% endif %}">{{ helpers.product_title(product.title) }}</h3>
        <p class="product-teaser__price{% if className %} // {{ className }}__price{% endif %}">{{ product.defaultPrice|currency(cart.currency) }}</p>

        <p>
            <a href="{{ product.url }}" class="btn // btn--sub">View Product</a>

            {% if className == "product-teaser--featured" %}
                <a href="{{ category.url }}" class="btn // btn--base">{{ category.title }} Range</a>
            {% endif %}
        </p>
    </div>
{% endmacro %}
```

Comment: I never knew you could pass imported macros into a macro. That opens up all sorts of possible complexity!

Comment: I made a mistake, you can't pass imported macros into other macros. You'll need to import them in each macro that uses it.